# Zurb foundation datepicker show in three character week day names instead of two character

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, zurb-foundation

On the Foundation-datepicker plugin (not related to ZURB), is it possible to show week day name in three character (MON, TUE, WED etc.) in foundation datepicker? ([source code on github](https://github.com/najlepsiwebdesigner/foundation-datepicker))

I mean, instead of:
MO  TU  WE  TH  FR  SA SU

Show these:
MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN.

```
<script>
$(function(){
  $('#dpt').fdatepicker({
        format: 'mm-dd-yyyy hh:ii'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there, did it helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in line 1128 in the code of the following file - **js/foundation-datepicker.js** replace this line

```
daysMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa", "Su"],
```

with this line:

```
daysMin: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
```

note that you'll have to check the css for any updates for the styling.

enjoy